# jboss javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException

Tags: exception, jboss, locking, optimistic

I am using jboss version 5.1.0.GA and am running gss service on it (https://code.google.com/p/gss/).
I ran into problem of javax.persistence OptimisticLockException.
Stack trace is as following:

```
    07 Jan 2014 00:06:15,966 pool-45617-thread-1 WARN  () [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLoggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator_2] TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeC
ompletion - failed for com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple@417f3b89
javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.wrapStaleStateException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:627)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:588)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$1.beforeCompletion(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:513)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:101)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:269)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:89)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:177)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1423)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:137)
        at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.endTransaction(TxPolicy.java:170)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:87)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:190)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:186)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:176)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:216)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:207)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:164)
        at $Proxy379.updateFileContents(Unknown Source)
        at org.gss_project.gss.server.webdav.milton.GssFolderResource$5.call(GssFolderResource.java:305)
        at org.gss_project.gss.server.webdav.milton.GssFolderResource$5.call(GssFolderResource.java:302)
        at org.gss_project.gss.server.ejb.TransactionHelper$1.call(TransactionHelper.java:78)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:207)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [org.gss_project.gss.server.domain.Folder#7857644]
```

All of the project source is available here: https://code.google.com/p/gss/source/browse/

Can you please point me in some direction and help out with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

An javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException is throwed when a user tries to update a record in database after some other user has modified it. This is handled automatically by the JPA provider if the Entity has one field (column) annotated with @Version.

Here is full explanation: http://gerrydevstory.com/2012/06/23/optimistic-locking-with-jpa/